# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Tags: php, pdo, execute

index.php:

```
$db = new Db();
$param = [':name' => 'Alex'];
$data = $db->sql('select * from test where name = :name',$param)->query();
var_dump($data);
```

and get the error :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean
```

Db.php

```
   public function sql($sql,array $params = null)
    {   
        $sql = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

        if($params){
            foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
                $sql->bindParam($key, $param);
            }
        }

        $this->statement = $sql;
        return $this; 
    }


    public function query($type = 1)
    {
      $statement = $this->statement->execute();

      return ($type == 1) ? $statement->fetchAll(static::$DB_FETCH) : $statement->fetch(static::$DB_FETCH);
    }
```

If I running in the sql() method, execute() and fetch() the data inside it , it can truly get the data , but put the execute() and fetch() to the query() method, getting the error message, Any Idea?  ;

Comment: `false` means that your query failed, use http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php to see the error.

Comment: @u_mulder I var_dump(statement) and got ture ./Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test/Program/Component/Db.php:60:boolean true

Comment: Use the function in my comment, __please__

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test/Program/Component/Db.php:61:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code.
In this line:

```
$statement = $this->statement->execute();
```

The `execute()` method is [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).
This is the signature:

```
public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )
```

Which means it returns boolean.
Your mistake is you are trying to call `fetchAll()` on a boolean.

For more information about the error message, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function query($sql,array $params = null,$type = 1)
    {
      $sql = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

      if($params){
          foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
              $sql->bindParam($key, $param);
          }
      }

      $this->statement = $sql;

      $statement = $this->statement->execute();

      return ($type == 1) ? $statement->fetchAll(static::$DB_FETCH) : $statement->fetch(static::$DB_FETCH);
    }
```

And

```
$data = $db->query('select * from test where name = :name',$param);
```

Comment: This case is good, but i still can not understand the wrong that I made.

Comment: it's better to return a statement. Makes your function WAY more flexible and useful

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement = $this->statement->execute();
```

Your code is returning a bool value. But your statement object is cotaining your processed data. By the way you have to get returned values from main statement via:

```
 $this->statement->fetchAll();
```

Regards.